# Remember different monitor configurations

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-manager

Ubuntu 22.10

So, I work from home a few days a week, and have different monitor setups at home and in the office.

Every time I go back and forth, ubuntu assumes the previous setup until I change it manually. This mainly impacts the position, which can be annoying when moving the cursor between screens.

Is there a way to save monitor presets? Ideally with the system identifying the setup based on the monitors plugged in, but even flipping  a switch/running a script would be fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need to write the script.

Comment: @David Do you know where the configuration is stored?